# Desaturation using pixastic - jquery

Tags: jquery

I use pixastic jquery plugin and i get this error :  "Unable to get image data from canvas because the canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data."

I came to know that this err comes when the image is not in same domain but .. my image is in local filesystem

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#phone1").load(function() {

         $("#phone1").pixastic("desaturate");
   });

});
```

Comment: i get this error only with chrome .. works fine in firefox,safari,IE

Answer (score 1):

I also found this 'problem' with Chrome on other cross-domain ajax load commands. It's some enhanced security setting in Google Chrome I haven't really managed to pin down.

So maybe this doesn't really count as a solution but I found that serving the development pages through a local webserver like MAMP,LAMP or WAMP (all easy apache installs) solves the trick (or put the development on an online server)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem today.

There are two approaches:

1. **(unsafe)** change Pixastic's code to use this trick: `dataImg.crossOrigin = ''`
2. (safe) enable [CORS headers](http://enable-cors.org/) on the source of images

If you have control over the source of your images and it's on another domain/subdomain I suggest to use solution 2. If the source is someone else and *really* trusted you can use 1.

Otherwise you're out of luck.